# Merge rows with same date to filll blanks/Nans using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataset (100K rows) of chemical parameters and the date they were measured for numerous locations (IDs). Some of these records have been split between rows with the same date. I would like to recombine them.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.array([["Site 1","1/12/2029",3,0.001,np.nan],["Site 1","1/12/2029",np.nan,np.nan,3],["Site 1","2/12/2029",7,np.nan,3],
                           ["Site 1","2/12/2029",np.nan,0.001,np.nan],["Site 2","1/12/2029",3,0.001,3],["Site 1","3/12/2029",5,0.005,3],
                           ["Site 2","2/12/2029",np.nan,np.nan,3],["Site 2","2/12/2029",np.nan,0.001,np.nan]]),
                 columns=["ID","Date", 'Na', 'SO4','Mg'])
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'],format= '%d/%m/%Y',dayfirst=True)
df1

Out[8]:
       ID       Date   Na    SO4   Mg
0  Site 1 2029-12-01    3  0.001  nan
1  Site 1 2029-12-01  nan    nan    3
2  Site 1 2029-12-02    7    nan    3
3  Site 1 2029-12-02  nan  0.001  nan
4  Site 2 2029-12-01    3  0.001    3
5  Site 1 2029-12-03    5  0.005    3
6  Site 2 2029-12-02  nan    nan    3
7  Site 2 2029-12-02  nan  0.001  nan
```

I have deliberately jumbled the orders a bit and there may still be some columns that are empty in my data.

Result I would like is:

```py
Out[2]:
       ID       Date   Na    SO4 Mg
0  Site 1 2029-12-01    3  0.001  3
1  Site 1 2029-12-02    7  0.001  3
2  Site 2 2029-12-01    3  0.001  3
3  Site 1 2029-12-03    5  0.005  3
4  Site 2 2029-12-02  nan  0.001  3
```

Which is the values for the chemical parameters (Na, SO4, and Mg) for the same date and ID condensed, removing the nan values (nans will remain where there is no entry for a date and ID in any rows with that date and ID.

I tried this:

```py
df_new=df1.groupby(['ID','Date']).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'Date').fillna(method='ffill')
df_new

Out[7]:
                         ID       Date   Na    SO4   Mg
ID     Date
Site 1 2029-12-01 1  Site 1 2029-12-01  nan    nan    3
       2029-12-02 0  Site 1 2029-12-02    3  0.001  nan
                  2  Site 1 2029-12-02    7    nan    3
                  3  Site 1 2029-12-02  nan  0.001  nan
       2029-12-03 5  Site 1 2029-12-03    5  0.005    3
Site 2 2029-12-01 4  Site 2 2029-12-01    3  0.001    3
       2029-12-02 6  Site 2 2029-12-02  nan    nan    3
                  7  Site 2 2029-12-02  nan  0.001  nan
```

But this doesn't seem to do what I had hoped, and also introduces a weird index column.

Comment: There is always only one non misisng values per combinations of `ID` and `Date` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible more non missing values per combinations `ID` and `Date` then solution is more complicated:

```
#because sample data     
df1 = df1.mask(df1 == 'nan')

df1 = (df1.sort_values(['ID','Date'])
          .groupby(['ID','Date'])
          .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
          .drop_duplicates())
print (df1)
       ID       Date   Na    SO4 Mg
0  Site 1 2029-12-01    3  0.001  3
2  Site 1 2029-12-02    7  0.001  3
5  Site 1 2029-12-03    5  0.005  3
4  Site 2 2029-12-01    3  0.001  3
6  Site 2 2029-12-02  NaN  0.001  3
```

Comment: Here we agree:)

Answer (score 1):

If there are always only one non misisng values per combinations of `ID` and `Date`, you'll only need [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)( **This is faster** than `groupby.apply`).
Otherwise, you should use **@Jezrael's** solution:

```
#df1 = df1.replace('nan',np.nan)
df1.groupby(['ID','Date'],as_index = False).first()
```

**Output**

```
       ID       Date   Na    SO4 Mg
0  Site 1 2029-12-01    3  0.001  3
1  Site 1 2029-12-02    7  0.001  3
2  Site 1 2029-12-03    5  0.005  3
3  Site 2 2029-12-01    3  0.001  3
4  Site 2 2029-12-02  NaN  0.001  3
```